# Azure Data Factory Error while storing files in hierarchical format using Data Flow

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage, dataflow

I am using Azure's Data Flow activity to transform my data and store the cleansed file as csv in blob storage in hierarchical format.

This is my dataflow activity, where in derived columns I have added columns for year, month, and day as I want my folder to be structured in this format
[image]

Added the columns to dynamically accept the year, month, and day in the columns
[image]

Then I am setting the Key partitioning to pass the column values so that folder structure can be created in this manner
[image]

This is my sink dataset where I want the hierarchical folders to be created.

[image]

But not sure why, when I run the pipeline I get the following error.
[image]

The script for Data Flow.

[image]

I am not sure what I have done wrong and how to resolve this. Any help is appreciated.

Many Thanks!!

Comment: Configuration looks fine. Does it write some rows, then fail? I'm wondering if you might have some data in those columns that is causing the connector to fail when writing to your storage account ... does the account you have in your Linked Service have permissions to create folders and write files?

Comment: Yes I have permission to create folders and write files to it. The columns created in the derived column has year, month and day which was added by dynamic expression, since I am trying to partition the folders by those values

Comment: I have added the configuration for the derived column in the post.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to answer dataflow issues if you post the script(Click on button on top right). The UI screens will miss a lot of detail.

Comment: I have added the script for the Data Flow, you could you please review the post again. Thanks

Comment: The way this is configured all files in a single run will always in a single location(single this is against current date). For using key partitioning you should include all these columns in the sink's input schema(processeddate etc). These 3 columns will be in the sink's extended schema. If you do not wish that you need to use 'As data in column' option. There are many helpful videos on this online.